# Is it possible to run a particular line of Python code instead of the whole script in Thonny?

Tags: python, ide, thonny

I just installed Thonny and took a look at some beginner guides. I can easily run whole script by pressing "play" button (or pressing F5). However I could not figure out how to run only some particular lines in the script.

Comment: This isn't directly possible in most programming languages (with a few key exceptions). If you want to run line-by-line, you can either comment out the lines you don't want to run (cmd+/ will usually comment out all the lines currently selected by the cursor) or put in some breakpoints and run it in debug mode.

Comment: let’s assume that I have a 5-line script and I run it. after that I add a sixth line into my script. so, what you mean is that it is not possible to run only sixth line and I have to run all (?) I have to run all lines from top to bottom any time I add a new line on my script (?)

Comment: Well, yes, because you're *running the script*. If you want to run one line at a time, like to experiment or something, you can open a python console (I don't know how to do this in Thonny, but if you open a command prompt and type `python` you end up in a space where you can essentially write a script continuously executing line-by-line). But in general, running single lines of code isn't that useful, and that's what scripts are for - bundle a bunch of code together so you can run it all at once.

Comment: ok then, I understand that I have to run it all over it. So the packages and data sets will be imported every time, variables will be created over and over again and then I get the result.

Comment: It is not possible in current version

Answer (score 0):

In Thonny there is a ‘de-bugger’ button at the top (or f6) and if you press that you run through your code one line at a time. It is extremely useful for when you are trying to find out where your code goes wrong. I hope you find this helpful :).

Answer (score 0):

It is a very useful feature and I think Thonny is lacking it currently but is exist in other IDEs such as spyder. Hope the developers will make it happen in future versions. This is useful when you read a big data that takes some time to read. This facility allows us to skip reading the files (which we do in the case of executing the whole script) and execute other lines.